# How to find elements with value and set a class in this closest <tr> in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to find element that have value="123". The value of element will dynamic generated. All element with different values are include with #first-flight. I want to find the same and set a class on that closest `<tr>` with 'selected'.
Actually, I want the smallest value of all element which have name='firstAmt' and type is 'hidden' and add a class 'selected' to that `<tr>` closest. 
Anyone you help me?

Here is my HTML Markup:

```
<table id="first-flight" class="table tbl-flight-listing-2 dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="top" colspan="6">
                <span class="strong">Kolkata <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Mumbai</span>
                <span class="weak">Sun, 15 Nov</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            <th>Airlines</th>
            <th>Depart</th>
            <th>Arrive</th>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">7400</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="7400">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">4793</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="4793">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">5799</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="5799">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">4238</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="4238" class="kkk">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">7690</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="7690">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">8600</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="8600">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">7990</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="7990">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">11433</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="11433">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
                <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
                <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
            </td>
            <td>12:35</td>
            <td>
                <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
                <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
            </td>
            <td class="fare-price">
                <span class="price">15799</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="15799">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I try to find the smallest value with following jquery code:

```
var valuesAmt = $('#first-flight tbody tr td.fare-price input[name=firstAmt]').map(function () {
    return parseInt($(this).val());
}).get();
var minimum = Math.min.apply(null, valuesAmt);
alert(minimum);
```

Its working fine. Now I want to add a class on that `<tr>` in which having the smallest (minimum) value.

Any one help me to build this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use attribute-value selector as follow:

```
$('#first-flight tbody tr td.fare-price input[name=firstAmt][value="' + minimum + '"]')
    .closest('tr') // Get closest ancestor tr
        .addClass('selected'); // Add class 'selected' to it
```

The selector used here is the same that is used to get all the input elements having name as *firstAmt* and value of `minimum` and to select the closest ancestor `<tr>`, `closest('tr')` is used.

```js
var valuesAmt = $('#first-flight tbody tr td.fare-price input[name=firstAmt]').map(function() {
  return parseInt($(this).val());
}).get();
var minimum = Math.min.apply(null, valuesAmt);


$('#first-flight tbody tr td.fare-price input[name=firstAmt][value="' + minimum + '"]')
  .closest('tr').addClass('selected')
  .children('td').first().find(':radio').prop('checked', true); // To select the radio
```

```css
.selected {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="first-flight" class="table tbl-flight-listing-2 dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="top" colspan="6">
        <span class="strong">Kolkata <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Mumbai</span>
        <span class="weak">Sun, 15 Nov</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>&nbsp;</th>
      <th>Airlines</th>
      <th>Depart</th>
      <th>Arrive</th>
      <th>Duration</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">7400</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="7400">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">4793</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="4793">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">5799</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="5799">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">4238</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="4238" class="kkk">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">7690</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="7690">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">8600</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="8600">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">7990</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="7990">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">11433</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="11433">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="leftflight" value="">
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="airLogo">
                    <img src="img/airlines/AI.png" alt="Air India" title="Air India" height="23" width="27">
                </span>
        <span class="airNo weak">6E-595</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="arrtime">09:45</span>
        <span class="arrairline">Air India</span>
      </td>
      <td>12:35</td>
      <td>
        <span class="tottime">2h 50m</span>
        <span class="away weak">non-stop</span>
      </td>
      <td class="fare-price">
        <span class="price">15799</span>
        <input type="hidden" name="firstAmt" value="15799">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Namaste Tushar Ji. Thank you. it's working fine ! :)

Comment: Welcome @SandipKr. Glad to help.